# Python: pyspark dataframe won't `show()` after join

Tags: python, join, pyspark, nonetype

I have two pyspark dataframes that I'm trying to join.  I've joined many other dataframes in my program so far and haven't had issues.  I'm joining them like this

```
door_totaltime = Tot_time_Door.join(Tot_time_NonDoor, 'device_day_id', "outer")
```

and it runs fine in the IPython console.  `device_day_id` is just a concatenated string from a couple of common fields in the 2 tables.  I also tried

```
door_totaltime = Tot_time_Door.join(Tot_time_NonDoor, 
                                   ['DeviceId', 'day_', 'Id'], "outer")
```

Either way, when I call `door_totaltime.show()`, I get a HUGE error trace (shown below).  My join statement looks just like my other working join statements.  Might there be something in the dataset that's different that I should be accounting for, but I'm not?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-350-31793c2fda95>", line 1, in <module>
    door_totaltime.show()

  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 318, in show
    print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20))

  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in __call__
    answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)

  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)

  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
    format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o4143.showString.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1108.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.0 in stage 1108.0 (TID 29396, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "<ipython-input-295-805f64ccae27>", line 5, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor150.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 174, in main
    process()
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 169, in process
    serializer.dump_stream(func(split_index, iterator), outfile)
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 106, in <lambda>
    func = lambda _, it: map(mapper, it)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/local/share/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 70, in <lambda>
    return lambda *a: f(*a)
  File "<ipython-input-295-805f64ccae27>", line 5, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'

    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.read(PythonRDD.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner$$anon$1.<init>(PythonRDD.scala:234)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRunner.compute(PythonRDD.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.python.BatchEvalPythonExec$$anonfun$doExecute$1.apply(BatchEvalPythonExec.scala:87)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:796)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:323)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
1 more
```

Comment: is this the one that is failing? `['DeviceId', 'day_', 'Id']` ? bit unclear

Comment: both versions of the code I provided are failing: `'device_day_id'` and `['DeviceId', 'day_', 'Id']` give the same error.